# Converting from OnClientClicking to onClientClick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

I currently have a JavaScript method that looks to see if the page is validated and if so allows the user to press a create button and throws a radconfirm, the problem i am having is that if i use a radButton this works perfectly but when using an ASP:Button it wont allow the radConfirm to show up and skips past it.

This is the method:

```
function ShowConfirm(clickedButton, args) {

        var validated = window.Page_ClientValidate('POPgroup');

        if (validated) 
        {
            args.set_cancel(true);

            function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
                if (arg == true) {
                    clickedButton.click();
                }
            }
            var text = "Please make sure all fields are completed correctly as once" +
                    " accepted the proof of purchase will be submitted and no further " +
                    "changes will be allowed. Are you sure you wish to continue?";
            radconfirm(text, confirmCallBackFn,350,100,null,"Confirm");
            }
        }
```

This is the button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="AddProofOfPurchaseButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
ValidationGroup="POPgroup" CssClass="claim_header_create_button" 
OnClick="AddProofOfPurchaseButton_OnClick" OnClientClick="ShowConfirm(this); 
 return false;" />
```

How would i change this code to work with the asp button and not the radbutton? also why does this happen what is the difference between OnClientClicking(Telerik) to onClientClick(asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles across the same problem the answer i found to my problem was this.

```
function ShowConfirm(button) {

        var validated = window.Page_ClientValidate('POPgroup');

        if (validated) {

            function CallbackFn(arg) {
                if (arg) {
                    __doPostBack(button.name, "");
                }
            }
            var text = "Please make sure all fields are completed correctly as once" +
                    " accepted the proof of purchase will be submitted and no further " +
                    "changes will be allowed. Are you sure you wish to continue?";
            radconfirm(text, CallbackFn, 350, 100, null, "Confirm");
        }
    }
```

And the button like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="AddProofOfPurchaseButton" runat="server" Text="Submit"
 ValidationGroup="POPgroup" CssClass="claim_header_create_button"
 OnClick="AddProofOfPurchaseButton_OnClick" OnClientClick="ShowConfirm(this); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem few days back. Actually **Radbutton**'s are set **true** for Autopostback by default, so if you want to achieve this in **radbutton**! then,
you need to change the postback property (you can change it in jscript later) and also the **causesvalidation** check.

```html
<telerik:RadButton ID="AddProofOfPurchaseButton" Text="Submit" CssClass="claim_header_create_button" runat="server" 
ValidationGroup="POPgroup" OnClientClicking="ShowConfirm" CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="false" OnClick="AddProofOfPurchaseButton_OnClick"></telerik:RadButton>
```

and also in script

```
function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
if (arg == true) {
clickedButton.set_autoPostBack(true);   //removed -->clickedButton.click();   
}  else { clickedButton.set_autoPostBack(false); }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply my code in the question actually works in a radbutton the problem i was having was getting it to work with asp button instead the problem i found was "args.set_cancel(true);" stops navigation which is a telerik method so of course didnt work with asp button.